# how to disable hover affect when searchbox is focused?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have typed CSS code for a search box in my web. but when it focused still hover is working. how can i disable this hover effect when search box is focused and enable it again when focus effect has removed???

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: You will need to provide sample code outline before someone could provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `:not(:focus)` to your selector like this:

```css
input:hover:not(:focus) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hover or click" />
```